# How to dynamically add fields to a select statement in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I have a large table of data in Snowflake that contains many fields with a name prefix of 'RAW_'. In order to make my table more manageable, I wish to exclude all of these 'RAW_' fields completely from my select statement.

To do this manually is problematic for me as I normally have anywhere from 90-120 fields I would need to otherwise manually sift through and place in this select statement.  It is therefore critical that I have a solution that allows me to dynamically add these fields into my main select statement that don't contain the prefix of 'RAW_' .

Here is a snippet of test data ...

```
insert into reviews values
    ('abc', 4, NULL, 1, 'NO'),
    ('xyz', 3, 'some', 1, 'haha'),
    ('lmn', 1, 'what', 4, NULL);
```

and this is my 'manual' solution, (noting that I would normally be adding 90-120 fields manually that don't have a 'RAW_' prefix)

```
select 
name , 
acting_rating 
from reviews;
```

getting me this desired output...

[image]

If I have the ability to add these non 'RAW_' fields to my select statement dynamically (noting that I'm usually needing to add 90-120 at a time), that would be great

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to exclude the columns with a prefix (yet). Snowflake supports EXCLUDE but you need to enter the exact column names.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/select.html#parameters

You can create views, so you don't need to write all columns every time you use a select.

You can create a stored procedure to generate the select statements for any table.